# What is this line of code doing in a react method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
   addPerson = (person) => {
     this.setState(prevState => {
     const people = [...prevState.people, person]
     return {people}
    })
   }
```

The line in question is
const people = [...prevState.people, person]

I realize the ...prevState.people
is spreading the previous state of the people array into (a new array?? [ ] ??) i'm confused about what the comma here signifies.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of  `[...prevState.people, person]` as being a fancy way of writing [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
prevState.people.push(person) // returns the new length of the `people` array
```

However, there is a key difference, here, `.push` modifies the `prevState.people` array. Whereas using:

```
[...prevState.people, person] // "returns" this array
```

gives a *new array*, leaving `prevState.people` untouched. So, you can save the new array in a variable. In your example, it is saved into the variable `people`.

For example, if you take the array:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
```

And spread it into another array:

```
const b = [...a, 4];
```

Then the spread operator here is saying dump/move the contents of `a` into the *new array*, followed by a `4` which is another element in the *new array*.

Thus the output of `b` would be:
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [...a, 4]; // create a new array, put the elements of 'a' into this new array. Add another element '4' to the end of this new array

console.log(b);
```

You can read more about the spread syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

This means you are created new array and pushing `person` in this array. This is called spread operator. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is equivalent to the code below.

```
addPerson = (person) => {
     const prevState = this.state;
     const people = [...prevState.people,person];
     this.setState({person:person});
   }
```

`addPerson` is function which is passing person as a parameter.Both codes set the state of person.

```
const prevState = this.state;
```

The constant `prevState` gets the current state.

```
const people = [...prevState.people,person];
```

The above code takes the people object from current state, updates the person value of it and then passes it onto a constant variable people.

```
this.setState({person:person});
```

The above code updates the person state. it can also be written as below.

```
this.setState({person:person})
```